# How can I add up numbers that appear in class names?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom

Take the following code:

```
<div id="work">
    <div class="large-{{columns}} large-offset-{{columns}} columns projects">                       
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that `<div class="large-{{columns}} large-offset-{{columns}} columns projects">` can be generated an indefinite amount of times inside `#work`, and `{{columns}}` generates a number between 0 and 12.

What I want to do is run some JavaScript that goes through the numbers generated by `{{columns}}` and every time the sum is about to surpass 12, the associated divs get wrapped inside a new div with class "row".

The resulting HTML might look like this:

```
<div id="work">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="large-8 large-offset-4 columns projects"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="large-6 large-offset-0 columns projects></div>
    <div class="large-6 large-offset-0 columns projects"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="large-4 large-offset-0 columns projects"></div>
    <div class="large-8 large-offset-0 columns projects"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="large-12 large-offset-0 columns projects"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the `{{columns}}` values from each div's class name with the following regular expression:

```
/large-(\d+)\s* large-offset-(\d+)/
```

This computes the delta that should be added to the running sum:

```
var matches = /large-(\d+)\s* large-offset-(\d+)/.exec(item.className),
    delta = parseInt(matches[1], 10) + parseInt(matches[2], 10);
```

You can make new row divs with `document.createElement` and fill them with clones of the original divs.

Demonstration:

```js
function makeRowDiv(buildRow) {
  var row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'row';
  for (var i = 0; i < buildRow.length; ++i) { 
    row.appendChild(buildRow[i]);
  } 
  return row;
}

window.onload = function () {
  var work = document.getElementById('work'),
      items = work.getElementsByTagName('div'),
      newWork = document.createElement('div');
  var buildRow = [],
      count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (item.className.indexOf('columns') == -1) {
      continue;
    }
    // Extract the desired value.
    var matches = /large-(\d+)\s* large-offset-(\d+)/.exec(item.className),
        delta = parseInt(matches[1], 10) + parseInt(matches[2], 10);
    if (count + delta > 12 && buildRow.length != 0) {
      newWork.appendChild(makeRowDiv(buildRow));
      count = 0;
      buildRow = [];
    }
    buildRow.push(item.cloneNode(true));
    count += delta;
  } 
  if (buildRow.length != 0) {
    newWork.appendChild(makeRowDiv(buildRow));
  } 

  // Replace work with newWork.
  work.parentNode.insertBefore(newWork, work);
  work.parentNode.removeChild(work);
  newWork.id = 'work';
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}
#work .row {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 8px;
  background: #deedff;
  border: 1px solid #c4d1e1;
}
#work .row div {
  /* display: inline; */
  padding: 1px 4px 2px 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #fff3fc;
  border: 1px solid #ded3dc;
}
#work .row div div {
  /* display: inline; */
  padding: 1px 4px 2px 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="work">
  <div class="large-8 large-offset-4 columns projects">
    <div class="child-div"><p>8</p></div>
    <div class="child-div"><p>4</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 large-offset-0 columns projects">
    <div class="child-div"><p>6</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 large-offset-3 columns projects">
    <div class="child-div"><p>3</p></div>
    <div class="child-div"><p>3</p></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="large-4 large-offset-0 columns projects">
    <div class="child-div"><p>4</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-8 large-offset-0 columns projects">
    <div class="child-div"><p>8</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 large-offset-6 columns projects">
    <div class="child-div"><p>6</p></div>
    <div class="child-div"><p>6</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have enough horizontal space, you can uncomment the CSS line `/* display: inline; */` to see the children of each row div arranged side by side.

Comment: This works perfectly on its own but breaks when adding child divs inside the .columns divs.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: For example: 

`<div id="work">
  <div class="large-8 large-offset-4 columns projects">
    <div class="child-div"><p>some content</p></div>
  </div>
</div>`

I'm trying to make this work with the Foundation framework, each .columns will contain content, divs, img tags, text and so on..

Comment: If that's what you were looking for, please accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `split` or `replace` to get your integers and sum them up as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673729/is-there-an-equivalent-in-jquery-to-phps-preg-replace#7673741).

Example:

```
var str = 'large-8 large-offset-6';

var large = str.replace(/.*large-(\d+)/, '$1');
var offset = str.replace(/.*large-offset-(\d+)/, '$1');
```

Then use a solution such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366529/wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-div#3366539) to get your wrappers.

Example:

```
var divs = $("#work > .columns");
var count = <count how many cols are need to reach sum>
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=count) {
 divs.slice(i, i+count).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
}
```

I'm sure you can clean it up and finish it off but should give you the idea. I will complete when I get time tonight.